# Android Facebook SDK "Sessionless Request needs token but missing either application ID or client token"

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I was trying to make an app mentioned in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/ but I am facing an issue. I can run the app and login with my FB account but I cannot get my name on Facebook.
This is the error when I try to get my name:

```
07-09 00:36:12.275: D/Request(28372): Warning: Sessionless Request needs token but missing either application ID or client token.
```

I think the problem is about authentication or some permission related to access FB database.
Any opinion would be appreciated..

And this is the code I am working on:

```
package com.example.firstface;

import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException;
import android.content.pm.Signature;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.facebook.Request;
import com.facebook.Response;
import com.facebook.Session;
import com.facebook.SessionState;
import com.facebook.model.GraphUser;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // start Facebook Login         
        Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

          // callback when session changes state
          @Override
          public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            if (session.isOpened()) {
                Log.d("Info : ", session.getApplicationId());
              // make request to the /me API
              Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                // callback after Graph API response with user object
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                  if (user != null) {
                    TextView welcome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcome);
                    welcome.setText("hello " + user.getName() + "!");
                  }
                }
              }).executeAsync();
            }
          }
        });
    }

    @Override
      public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
          super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
          Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
      }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove onActivityResult from Fragment then add method on Activity page

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

It works for me !!!!!

Comment: This worked for me. I was about to hit my head on wall. thanks for sharing :)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
       <string name="app_id">999999999999999</string>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />
```